# Where is filter in TFS 2012 defined?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have added a new nuget package to my solution.

In the "Team View -> Pending Changes -> Detected Changes" there are *some* of the files, but /lib folder is ignored. As a result CI build breaks.

**Question:** where is it specified in TFS (or Visual Studio?) to exclude /Lib folder (or files inside /Lib folder)?

Comment: Check the definition of your workspace.

Comment: No. Not there. Unless there is more than one workspace settings places.

Comment: Sorry, _what's_ not there? Do you mean that your workspace definition has no exclusions?

Comment: Correct. I can not figure out how to specify exclusions for workspace, or even _see_ list of exclusions for a workspace.

Comment: In previous versions, there were no "exclusions". A workspace could have lines marked as "cloaked". I don't know how that's changed for VS2012, if at all. You might try to assume there are no such "exclusions" and look for a different reason that explains the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I suspect that there is an exclusion pattern, but I have no control over it. Because folder is there, but I can't see it.

Comment: I recommend you drop your suspicion. It doesn't fit the way things have been done in the past. Another suggestion: try renaming the "Lib" folder to "Foo" and see if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 11):

Given you're using TFS2012 I assume you're using a local workspace. For local workspaces files are ignored using the `.tfignore` file. Check if you have that file present and if there is an exclusion for the `/lib` folder in it.

Also note that by default certain files are ignored, such as the `.dll` files that would be in the `/lib` folder of the nuget package.  If a folder has no files to include it will not be shown in pending changes. You will have to add it manually via source control explorer.

Here's the [reference for the .tfignore file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore) if you want to see how it works.

Comment: @GuyBertental To ignore files or folders from the server you need to 'cloak' them in your workspace mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly determine the location of your .tfignore file by choosing to ignore something in your detected changes. This will cause the .tfignore file to appear in your "Included Changes" with the new ignore setting (it will be created if it didn't already exist). From here you can double click the file to open it up for editing.